# Android Studio does not recognize Kotlin code - (Arctic Fox)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

After cleaning the Android-Studio cache (`File-> Invalidate Cache/Restart`)
Kotlin code is not recognized by the Android Studio and code suggestions are not appearing.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This issue will not be solved through Invalidate cache as it will only clear the project cache, For the perfect solution you must have to clear entire android studio cache.
The only solution works in this situation is clearing cache of latest android studio.

Steps to clear Android studio cache:

**C drive** > **users** > **User** > **AppData** **Local** > **Google** > **latest Android studio version** > **caches**

Delete all files on caches

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to stack overflow.
Don't worry if it happens to you a couple of times. All you have to do is `make the project` (by clicking the hammer) or just `run the app` as follow:

[image]

Comment: Still does not solve the issue. :( I also clean .Gradle cache and rebuild but the issue is not solved.

Comment: Another thing is if create a new project it also appears error but the code is running fine when build or run on the device.

Comment: When I build or run the project there is no crash it's run fine.

Comment: ok. Then don't worry if Androdi Studio makes these jokes sometimes. If you fill in it will only be a momentary thing. It happens often. :-) the important thing is that build. I understand that it can be annoying but it is not perfect software

Comment: I noticed that "C:\Users\USER_NAME\.android\cache"  folder is empty. As I know it supposes to be full with the cache files.